# Difference between the usage of void and int in this code

Tags: java, int, void

Currently a beginner, I wrote a simple program which uses getters and return values (current course). I'd like to ask when should I use the void solution and the int solution, if both gives me the same outcome?

I really hope the formatting isn't too terrible.

```
class Database {
    String name;
    int age;

    String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    int yearsPlusFifty() {
        int year = age + 50;
        return year;
    }

    void plusFifty() {
        int year2 = age + 50;
        System.out.println(year2);
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {

    Database person1 = new Database();
    person1.name = "Josh";
    person1.age = 30;

    int year = person1.yearsPlusFifty();
    System.out.println("The age plus 50 is: " + year);

    person1.plusFifty();
}
```

Comment: which method ? plusFifty() ?

Comment: `void` returns nothing `int` returns an Integer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the int method (yearsPlusFifty) as that one has one responsibility - to calculate the value. Println in plusFifty is a side effect, which is not desirable. Keep the responsibilities of calculating and printing separate (makes it more reusable, testable, and easier to understand).

Comment: So I should avoid printing out values in void methods, right?

Comment: Well, you should get rid of the void method and only ever call the int method from any place where you need the value, and then from that place you can print it, save it to a file, save it in a db, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, `void` should be used when your method does not `return` a value whereas `int` will be used when your method returns `int` value.

Now coming to your methods, they both are not same, they are doing two different things:

`int yearsPlusFifty()` -  adding 50 and returning `int` value

`void plusFifty()` - better rename to `printPlusFifty()` - this method does both adding plus printing as well

```
int yearsPlusFifty() {//only adding and returning int value
    int year = age + 50;
    return year;
}

  void printPlusFifty() {//adding + printing
        int year2 = age + 50;
        System.out.println(year2);
    }
```